# Selectively silence python output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a python script to process some data. The script accepts two parameters, one for the input file and second for the output file. I want to extend to allow writing to stdout so output can be piped to other processes. My problem is that currently I also output progress information during processing as it can take some time. Ideally, I'd like to only suppress progress information if the script is configured to output to stdout. One advantage is that all the real output is emitted at once at the end of execution and not interspersed during execution.

The way I see it have two options, both of which I've tried (and work) but not sure they're the most pythonic way. Either I can overload calls to `print()` or I can redirect stdout to `/dev/null` during processing when the output file is configured to stdout.

Overload `print()`

```py
if args.output_file.name == '<stdout>':
    def silent(*args, **kwargs):
        return

    global print
    print = silent
```

Redirect stdout

```py
if args.output_file.name == '<stdout>':
      out = open('/dev/null', 'w')
  else:
      out = sys.stdout

  with redirect_stdout(out):
      data = process_data()

write_output(data, args.output_file)
```

Overloading `print()` seems the least pythonic but at least it only effects calls to `print()` and not writing to stdout as a file. However, if I wanted to `print()` to stderr then that would also be suppressed.

Redirecting stdout seems cleaner except for the fact where I'm redirecting stdout to stdout if the script is writing to a regular file.

Comment: You should get familar with Python's logging module.

Comment: If you just want to solve this problem (not necessarily nicely) then overwrite `print` as you said, and wherever you want to do an error, use `sys.stderr.write('str')`

Comment: If you don't feel like overloading print(), you could define your own print function, but name it print2 or log. After defining the new print function, most editors would allow you to find and replace all instances of "print" with "print2" or "log".

Comment: Status information should go to `stderr`, precisely so that it can never be mistaken for input to another process.